# Get 2 variables from Ajax call in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get 2 variables from ajax in php. With one variable its working fine. New to ajax, so I am not sure how will I include a second variable. As of now I am getting the msg_count with out any issues. My ajax script is below:

```
function addmsg(type, msg) {

    $('#msg_count').html(msg);

}

function waitForMsg() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "notification/select.php",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 50000,

        success: function(data) {
            addmsg("new", data);
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg,
                1000
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg,
                15000);
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    waitForMsg();

});
```

select.php script is below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from notification where tousername='$tousername' and isread = 0";
       $result = $con->query($sql);
       $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
       $count = $result->num_rows;
       echo $count;
       $not=$row['notification'];
       echo $not;
```

I am able to pass the $count properly. I need to pass $not also to the ajax. How will I do that?

My edited php script to use it with a WHILE Loop is as follows:

```
$result= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from notification where tousername='$tousername' and isread = 0");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$count = $result->num_rows;
$not=$row['notification_msg'];
$res=[];
$res['count'] = $count;
$res['not'] = $not;       
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: pass an array `json_encode` it and use `dataType:json` in ajax request

Comment: do you  need to send more then one data from ajax to php or what ??

Comment: yes, as of now iam able to send the $count variable properly to ajax. Now as in my php script, i need to send $not variable also to my ajax.

Answer (score 3):

Like @guradio said, set `dataType : 'json'` inside ajax properties and `json_encode` data that you want to pass into success block like following code :

```
$.ajax({
   ....
   ....
   dataType : 'json', // added here
   success : function ( data ) {
     // access data from response
     // access it using data.count, data.not
     console.log(data)
     // just called like original code
     // passed on result `data`
     addmsg( type, data ); 
     // the rest of the code
   }
   ...
});

function addmsg(type, msg){
  // access it using msg.count, msg.not
  console.log(msg.count)
  $('#msg_count').html(msg);
}
```

In **Php** :

```
$sql = "SELECT * from notification where tousername='$tousername' and isread = 0";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$count = $result->num_rows;       
$not=$row['notification'];
// added here
echo json_encode( array( 'count' => $count, 'not' => $not ) );
```

**Edited :** This depend on how you want to store the data and populate it

```
// defined container outside loop
$res = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  $count = $result->num_rows;
  $not=$row['notification_msg']; 
  array_push( $res, array( 'count' => $count, 'not' => $not ) );

}    

echo json_encode($res);
```

**Suggestion(credited to guradio):**

Must be noted that, there is not necessary to add `async : true` inside ajax properties as the default behavior of Ajax is asynchronous and the default value of that is `TRUE` unless you wanna it to be false, but not recommended.

Comment: Sir i think it is also a good idea to remove the `async: true` i cant explain it i know you can :)

Comment: @guradio : seems so. Thanks for point it out :). Anyway you can edit my answer as this answer is an open source.

Comment: @guradio and Glazali. Its working fine. Thank you for the info. I need to add a WHILE Loop  on my php script. Do i need to change anything else other than the while loop in this scenario?

Comment: tips is, you need to populate data inside while loop and store them inside array container, and at the end `json encode` array container.

Comment: Yes i have done exactly same. I have edited the question with the php script with While Loop. Can u pls tell me what iam doing wrong?

Comment: Yes php part is correct now. But i guess i need to edit the ajax part also to accomodate the loop. May be i need to add  $.each(obj, function(index, value) {

Comment: yes, should be like that. Use any loop features either `$.each` or  native `for` to loop over returned result.